# Characterizing $r^*(g):∫_0^1(x-\frac{1}{g})x^{\frac{1}{gr-1}}\frac{\ln x}{(1+xgr)²}dx=0.$

Tags: calculus

The function $r^* : (1,\infty)  \mapsto (0,\infty) $ is implicitly defined as solution

$$r^*(g):∫_0^1(x-\frac{1}{g})x^{\frac{1}{gr-1}}\frac{\ln x}{(1+xgr)²}dx=0.$$

Numerically (via matlab), I can show that $r^*(g)>1$ for $g$ sufficiently large.

**Question**: How can one show analytically that $r^*(g)>1$ for $g$ sufficiently large?

What I know: The equation has indeed a unique solution. Rewriting the expression as $J(r,g)$ and $r^*$ as the solution to $$J(r^*(g),g)=0,$$ one can show that for $r$ small, $J(r,g)<0$ and $r$ large, $J(r,g)>0$. This establishes existence of a solution. Moreover, for $r<r^*$, $J(r,g)<0$ and for $r>r^*$, $J(r,g)>0$. This establishes uniqueness. Finally, one can easily see that as $g \rightarrow \infty$, $gr^*(g)\rightarrow \infty$.